# SQL syntax issues with creating table

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I am having trouble writing DDL scripts to create tables. I have written the following code to create the `EMPLOYEE` and `CLIENT` table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    Employee_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fname VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    minit VARCHAR (1),
    lname VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR (55),
    start_date date,
    Job_type VARCHAR (20),
    PRIMARY KEY (Employee_id)
);


CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
    Client_id INT NOT NULL Auto_Increment,
    Rest_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    Pri_contact_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    Pri_phone CHAR (13) NOT NULL,
    Pri_email VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
    Cust_addr VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Client_id)
);
```

These tables are created with no issues.  However, when I try to create the `ORDER` table with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER (
    Order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Order_Placed CHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Delivered_on CHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Total VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
    Ship_addr VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Order_status VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Order_id)
);
```

I received this error:

> at line 27: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'ORDER (   Order_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   Order_Placed char(10) NOT NULL' at line 1.

I am not sure why I'm getting this error when I am using the same code from the previous tables that worked.

*I left out FK's out for now just to get the error figured

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word. I suggest you call it something else; 'orders' perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use backticks since `ORDER` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html):

```
CREATE TABLE `ORDER` (
    Order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Order_Placed CHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Delivered_on CHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    Total VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
    Ship_addr VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Order_status VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Order_id)
);
```

Comment: that worked!! thank you @Daerik

Comment: @houston if you've found the answer helpful to you, please mark it as accepted so it can help others.